# Can one safely use an OpenMP parallel loop with Armadillo?

Tags: c++, parallel-computing, armadillo

I have a C++ code performing some **Armadillo** computations in a loop. I'd like to parallelize this loop with **OpenMP**. But **Armadillo** automatically uses **OpenMP** for some computations. So, would the **OpenMP** parallelized loop cause an issue if I don't disable the automatic **Armadillo** parallelization ? Or can I safely use the parallelized loop without disabling that?

Answer (score 1):

Nested used of OpenMP is allowed. However, by default the second level will only get a single thread. If that's ok with you, you're good now. If you want the embedded level to be parallel too, set the environment variable `OMP_NESTED=true` or a function call `omp_set_nested(1)`.

Comment: Thanks! Would you know where is it documented?

Comment: The first hit if I google OMP_NESTED is https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse57.html